# When do rewarded video ads pay off?

Tags: admob, rewardedvideoad

I have a app with rewarded video ads. It has more than 10 impressions but I see no revenue.

How and when these video ads gets paid?

Comment: It's monthly, once you cross your payment threashold. Payment is transferred. Payment schedule information link for admob - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2772140?hl=en

Comment: After some tests with real users, I checked my revenue at admob the rewarded video didnt earned me anything. I added it in to application 1 day ago before check the revenue. Normally users can load video and show and watch video till it end also we tried to click it but we didnt get any revenue why?